# Update MutableList of MutableLiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack, mutablelivedata

I have a data class like:

```
data class Item(
    val name: String,
    val price: Int = 0
)
```

And a ViewModel like:

```
class MyViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    private val _items = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item>>()
    val items: LiveData<MutableList<Item>>
        get() = _items

    init {
        _items.value = mutableListOf()
    }

    fun addItem(){
         _items.value?.add(Item(name="newitem", price=10))
         _items.value = _items.value
    }
}
```

After `addItem()` is called, the new item is added to `_items` and `items`, which can be confirmed by `Log.d()`. However, the UI doesn't reflect the change, how can I fix this?

A worked approach is using `MutableLiveData<List<Item>>` instead of `MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item>>`, with `_items.value = _items.value?.plus(arrayListOf(newItem))`. However, that way I'm not able to udpate a single attribute of an added item, such as `price`.

Comment: What UI element are you using and how does it observe this. Is it a ListAdapter by any chance?

Comment: Try _items.notifyObserver() to notify all observers.

Comment: Replace `MutableLiveData<MutableList<T>>` with `MutableLiveData<List<T>>` and all your problems will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary mutableList, add the new item in the temp list, then update _items as: `_items.value = temp`. In this way, we changed the reference of mutableLiveData and triggered the update

Comment: In this example is `MutableList` actually needed if it actually gets fully replaced by another list?